# finding a specific element of a ListModel based on its properties in QtQuick 2.0

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a `ListModel` with an objectId role (integer and unique). I want to query the model to find other properties of an element with a specific objectId. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop other your model to retrieve each element one by one searching for your `objectId`

```
for(var i = 0; i < myModel.count; i++) {
  var elemCur = myModel.get(i);
  if(searchedId == elemCur.objectId) {
    console.log("Found it at index : ", i);
  }
}
```